# my comparison function didn't gives the right answer

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

whats wrong with this fucntion? it gives right ans just with the if condition in all other cases it gives wrong ans.
The four compass points can be abbreviated by single-letter strings as “N”, “E”, “S”, and “W”. Write a function turn_clockwise that takes one of these four compass points as its parameter, and returns the next compass point in the clockwise direction.

```
def turn_clockwise(v):
    if "N" == "N":
       return "E"
    elif "E" == "E":
       return "S"
    elif "S" == "S":
       return "W"
    elif "W" == "W":
       return "N"
    else:
       return "SORRY"
a = turn_clockwise("W") == "N"
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to use `v` in the comparisons. Right now you compare every direction to itself which will of course always be `True`.

```
def turn_clockwise(v):
    if v == "N":
       return "E"
    elif v == "E":
       return "S"
    elif v == "S":
       return "W"
    elif v == "W":
       return "N"
    else:
       return "SORRY"
```

You can also consider other, less "in-your-face" solutions (**not** necessarily more efficient):

```
def turn_clockwise(v):
    return {'N': 'E', 'E': 'S', 'S': 'W', 'W': 'N'}.get(v, 'SORRY')
```

or

```
def turn_clockwise(v):
    directions = 'NESW'
    try:
        return directions[(directions.index(v) + 1) % 4]
    except ValueError:
        return 'SORRY'
```